# SQL creating Table assignment

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create a Table for an Assignment, I have finished it but there is still a question. I don't understand what I have to do in the *ii*. I just wrote a VARCHAR command but I'm not sure if this is right, because there is written range instead of maximum 2 chars like the *viii*.
 Below is the whole exercise, hope somebody can help me.

> i.    Agent   Agent_code --   Unique PK    /   Non-unique PK
>
> ii. Agent   Areacode -- Valid range     /   Out of range
>
> iii.Agent   Phone --    Maximum 13chars     /   Size too large
>
> iv. Agent   Name -- NOT NULL    /    NULL
>
> v.  Agent   YTD_Sls --  Numeric     /    Wrong datatype
>
> vi. Customer    Cus_Code -- Unique PK     /  Non-unique PK
>
> vii.Customer    LName --    NOT NULL    /   NULL
>
> viii.Customer   Initial --  Maximum 2chars   /    Size too large
>
> ix.  Customer Renew_date -- DATE datatype     /     Incorrect datatype x.
>
> For example, the first business rule requires Agent_code to be a unique PK.  To confirm that this business rule has been implemented you will write an INSERT command that will attempt to insert a non-unique PK.  By looking at the first row of sample data below, we could attempt to insert the non-unique value of A101, which already exists in the table.  We would expect to see an error message confirming that a unique or PK was violated.  This would confirm that the business rule is being enforced by the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to put a check constraint on the Areacode field, so that all entries will conform to whatever the range of valid area codes are.

Then try to insert/update a row with an invalid Areacode to make sure that it fails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :), So you mean something like this right? CHECK (AREA_CODE > 0),

Comment: Yep, if your areacode field has data type integer and has no stated maximum. Then try setting a row with a areacode less than or equal to zero to get the desired exception.